# Как запустить внешнюю программу полностью независимо от основного приложения?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, execute

Классический вариант запуска:

```
system("cmd.exe");
```

Аналогично с `WinExec` и `QProcess`
НО! Если закрыть основную программу, запущенная внешняя программа тоже закрывается.
Отсюда, собственно, вопрос - как запустить программу независимой от основного приложения?

Comment: Классический вариант это CreateProcessW или ShellExecuteW

Comment: @user7860670 - я пробовал, но может что-то упустил - приведите код - посмотрим

Comment: `QProcess::startDetached` по идее делает то, что вам нужно

Comment: @BeardedBeaver возможно там нужно указывать особые параметры, но если просто запускать в startDetached("cmd.exe") - то при закрытии основного приложения - закроется и командная строка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я проверял в 5.15.2 и если запустить оконное приложение через `startDetached`, оно не закрывается после закрытия запускающего приложения. С командной строкой не получилось, потому что судя по всему начиная с 5.8 консольное окно в таком случае [скрывается](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53833).

Получилось добиться нужного вам поведения с помощью вот таких костылей:

```
QProcess process;
process.setProgram("cmd.exe");
process.setArguments(QStringList() << "/C" <<  "start" << "cmd.exe");
process.startDetached();
```

Списывал отсюда [отсюда](http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_6135_0.html)

Comment: Действительно, работает - спасибо